# Looking to Identify a LEGO creator set with a hook

Tags: set-identification, creator

Wandering the Internet not long ago I saw a LEGO set that I thought my kid would like because it had a hook (they are into tow trucks these days, so things with hooks catch their interest). Unfortunately I didn't bookmark the page nor write the name of the set down, and now it is impossible for me to find it again.

These are the things I remember about the set

- It was probably a LEGO creator set, because at first I thought the box contained 3 different vehicles and then I realized that you could build 3 different things with the same pieces.
- It had a hook of some kind (definitely) and probably a rope for the hook.
- One of the vehicles that you could build with the set was airborne, probably an helicopter, maybe a train.
- Other of the vehicles that you could build was a boat or ship (due to the size it looked more like a tiny tugboat).
- The predominant colors in the set were red and black (maybe dark blue?).

Note: I don't think it was the *LEGO Creator Cargo Heliplane*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Possibly [31045 Ocean Explorer?](https://brickset.com/sets/31045-1/Ocean-Explorer)

- Has hook
- Tugboat appearance
- 3-in-1
- Red and Dark Blue
- one model is a plane

[image]

If that's not it, you can browse Bricklink for sets containing [hooks](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?v=2&pg=1&q=hook&catLike=W). I'm guessing you probably saw the modern ["Hook with Towball"](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?itemType=P&itemNo=30395&in=S&v=2&oV=Y&srt=2&srtAsc=D) piece

Answer (score 7):

From your description I would assume it was 31045-1: Ocean Explorer - [Brickset](https://brickset.com/sets/31045-1/Ocean-Explorer)

Comment: That seems like a reasonable assumption. Welcome to Bricks.SE!